# WebView in Fragment - change orientation despite AndroidManifest declaration

Tags: android, webview, fragment

I need to change orientation of WebView in my Android application (after rotating phone), but all other parts of the application works in portrait orientation as fragments - I have set orientation value for the main activity as 'portrait'. Is it possible at all ?

Comment: So you want your app to stay always in portrait mode except your WebView, right ?

Comment: You can change the orientation of only certain fragments. Please refer this tutorial on how to do so: http://qtcstation.com/2011/12/fragment-activities-with-multiple-fragments/

Comment: The tutorial is so simple. Would it be too hard to add the main point to stackoverflow? Would make your post considerable better.